# find the difference between two file sizes and compare in an if statement - Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, filesize

Newbie to bash, trying to get something to work but having a fair bit of trouble.

I have two basic web pages, i want to find the number of bytes of each and then subtract new from old, if new has a greater than 30 character difference then echo that.

I'm currently at the below:

```
wcnew=“$(wc -c < new.html)”
echo $wcnew

wcold=“$(wc -c < old.html)”
echo $wcold
```

This gives me my wc's but i think i may be declaring them as strings so can't subtract them? Either way it's syntaxing out and i've been looking for a solution for a while now. any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: The double-quotes in your posted code are fancy unicode quotes, which the shell will not recognize as quotes. Always use plain ASCII double-quotes in shell scripts (and avoid text editors that helpfully convert them as "smart quotes"). Also, `stat` (as in `stat -f%z new.html`) is a better way to get the file size.

Comment: OH MY GOD. IT WAS THE QUOTES ALL ALONG. 

it all works now. thank you so much. i shall have a read of the page and if i get stuck come back but they are now getting treated as numbers so i can do arithmetic expressions on them. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` *only* has strings. What is also has, though, is an arithmetic expression, in which strings that *look* like numbers can be treated as numbers.

```
wcnew=$(wc -c < new.html)
wcold=$(wc -c < old.html)

echo $(( wcold - wcnew ))
```

Comment: i had tried this but it was syntaxing out :<.
the response to my echo for each is

    “ 9233"

when i run that final echo i get

test.sh: line 10: “    9233”: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "??    9233”")

Comment: just found out my quotes were causing issues. resolved :D